Training Tensorflow from Bigquery table
I need to train a tf model with a huge table on Bigquery.
I try to follow the example in the documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/io/tutorials/bigquery) but without success.
I can't figure out how i can separate the feature columns from the predictions.
As an example with iris dataset (only for this purpose, so no training and validation, because my issues is only on the connection):
df = pd.get_dummies(
    pd.read_csv("iris.csv",header = None ,names = ["sepal_length", "sepal_width", "petal_length", "petal_width", "class"]), 
    columns=["class"])\
    .rename(columns={"class_Iris-setosa":"setosa" ,"class_Iris-versicolor":"versicolor" ,"class_Iris-virginica":"virginica" })

client = bigquery.Client(project=PROJECT_ID,location = "europe-west3")
table = f"{PROJECT_ID}.{DATASET_ID}.{TABLE_ID}"
client.delete_table(table, not_found_ok=True)
job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    df, 
    table , 
    job_config=bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,),name='input'),
    keras.layers.Dense(12,activation="relu",name='dense'),
    keras.layers.Dense(3,activation="softmax",name='out')
])

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer="sgd", metrics=["accuracy"])

The dataset has the 4 features columns and the 3 categorical output, from the local pandas dataframe it's obvius:
x = df[["sepal_length", "sepal_width", "petal_length", "petal_width"]].to_numpy()
y = df[["setosa","versicolor","virginica"]].to_numpy()

model.fit(x=x , y =y , epochs=5)

But using tensorflow_io.bigquery i only have a big iterable dataset:
tensorflow_io_bigquery_client = BigQueryClient()
read_session = tensorflow_io_bigquery_client.read_session(
    "projects/" + PROJECT_ID,
    PROJECT_ID,
    "iris_nt",
    DATASET_ID,
    ["sepal_length", "sepal_width", "petal_length", "petal_width", "setosa","versicolor","virginica" ], 
    output_types=[tf.float64, tf.float64,tf.float64,tf.float64 ,tf.bool,tf.bool,tf.bool], 
    requested_streams=1,
    #data_format= tfio.bigquery.BigQueryClient.DataFormat.AVRO
)
dataset = read_session.parallel_read_rows()

how i can separate x and y ? how i can pass the x and y arguments to fit?
PS: I have tf version 2.17.
